# Load Type Catalog reference for loaded families

Tags: autodesk-forge

so working with additional families on REVIT we encountered a new need.
Whenever we have a .rvt file with additional loads of type catalogs and no original .rfa file, we want to process the .rvt through Forge and have a way of finding the .rfa file name or any information that was used to load type catalogs used in the current .rvt.

In other words, if I load a series of .rfa then I can know which object belongs to which .rfa.

Answer (score 0):

With Design Automation you can use the Revit API to open the RVT file and read the RFAs in it. The name of the family should match the name of the RFA used to create it.